# AS3 Math.random generating the same number

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to get a random number to be generated and if it fits the `if` conditional, will play the sound. This used to work but for some reason now, it only generates the same number. Please help!

```
var myNum:Number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, creakers);
function creakers(e:Event):void
{
trace(myNum);
if (myNum<10)
{ 
    creakSound.play();}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are generating random number outside of event listener. So you are never changing `myNum`. You need to move that inside the `creakers` method.

```
function creakers(e:Event):void
{
    var myNum:Number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000);
    trace(myNum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem there is that the myNum is a local variable inside another function(constructor) and u r trying to access the same variable in another function creakers..a local function defined in one function will be confined to that function only... so in order to make things right u should define the myNum variable inside the creakers function.

there is one other method also.... define this variable inside the class as a public or private variable. so that it can be used in multiple functions inside the class

```
class xx{
 public var mynum:Number
 function xx(){
   mynum = Math.random * 20000;
 }
 function creaker{
   trace(mynum);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate myNum every enterframe, you must make this calculation in your creakers function whose event is `Event.ENTER_FRAME`.

```
var myNum:uint;

function creakers(e:Event):void
{
    myNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000);
}

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, creakers);
```

**Remarks**

- Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000) is an `integer`, so myNum's type isn't
  `Number` but `uint`.
- myNum should rather be declared outside the function creakers
  because it's not useful to `declare` this variable every enterframe. You
  just need to attribute it a new value.